# Why won't synology CVS allow user login?

Tags: cvs, nas, synology

I'm trying to set up a CVS server on my synology NAS, but am getting a recurring error in actually accessing the cvs via login.  I'm also posting this on the synology server, but thought that I'd post here as it's probably more of a CVS issue than a Synology issue.

I followed these instructions to set up CVS
http://forum.synology.com/wiki/index.php/Step-by-step_guide_to_installing_CVS_server

Here's the result of login:

> $ cvs -d :pserver:user1@redacted.org:/opt/cvsroot login
>
> cvs login: authorization failed: server redacted.org rejected access to /opt/cvsroot for user user1

Results of various checks:

> $ Netstat -l | grep cvs
>
> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:cvspserver      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

..

> $ cat /etc/services | grep cvs
>
> cvspserver    2401/tcp            # CVS client/server operations
>
> cvspserver    2401/udp            # CVS client/server operations
>
> cvsup           5999/tcp  CVSup       # CVSup file transfer/John Polstra/FreeBSD
>
> cvsup           5999/udp  CVSup       # CVSup file transfer/John Polstra/FreeBSD

Synology details :: DS2411+ DSM 4.1-2661

The password I'm using is correct per /opt/cvsroot/CVSROOT/passwd
Permissions on passwd are chmod 400, and owned by cvs:cvs.

Any thoughts? Thanks for your help.

Comment: This question belongs on [sf], because it has nothing to do with coding and is about system administration.

Comment: You are correct, thanks; I'll move it over there.